# Expected required sample length to train a hidden Markov model

Tags: machine-learning, sample-size, hidden-markov-model, train

Say one wishes to train a hidden Markov model with $n$ hidden states, and (accidentally) the problem itself can be described with a hidden Markov model with $n$ (or less states). What is the expected number of samples one needs to learn such model correctly (with an error $<\epsilon$)?